# MongoDB authorization problem for command copydb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

i've a problem in my nodejs mongoDB script, it look like that

````
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const test = require('assert');
dotenv.config();
const url = process.env.MONGO_URI;
async function main(){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        const adminDb = client.db().admin();
        const mongoCommand = { copydb: 1, fromdb: "dbtest", todb: "newdbtest"};
        adminDb.command(mongoCommand, function(commandErr, data) {
            if (!commandErr) {
                console.log(data);
            } else {
                console.log(commandErr.errmsg);
            }
            client.close();
        });
    }
});
}
main().catch(console.error);```
````

But when i run this script, i have an error `not authorized on admin to execute command...`
and i don't understand why my user from MongoDB Atlas can't perform this operation
Can you help me ?
Is that because i have a free cluster ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of MongoDB?  The copydb command is removed in 4.2.

Comment: For older versions, check out [Required Access](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/command/copydb/index.html#required-access)